# PCIe loopback testing

Tags: pcie

I have a design using PCIe 4 lanes that interface between 2 CCAs and will be connected through a connector/flex connection.
In the event that the mate to either CCA is not available, I want to know how I can verify the signals to the connector of each CCA and then, if there is a loopback that I could use to test one CCA if the other isn't available. 
One CCA will have an ASIC/PCIe and the other will have a ZyncSoc/PCIe.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please define `CCA`.

Comment: I don't believe that PCIe has support for loopback testing (i.e. connecting TX to RX of same device). PCIe requires a root and an endpoint (or multiple endpoints), and a device can't be both root and EP.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: Many PCIe devices do support physical and logical loopback, but *only* if you have access to a number of very hidden registers.

Comment: JTAG Boundary scan?  If this is only for testing on production line.